# Defense against ClickJacking

Tags: http, security, browser

Is it enough if we implement x-frame-options to prevent against click jacking or we need to also provide the framebusting (framekilling) code mandatorily ?

I was following this article 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking

I can think that framebusting will be required for browsers which don't support x-frame-options.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Why did people downvote this question so much? I think it is a relevant, on-topic, legit question.

Comment: oh..i did not see it being down voted :)...may be its a trend now to downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X-Frame-Options header is very well supported across pretty much all browsers, at least with the 'deny' and 'sameorigin' values. Maybe IE 8+ is the weakest point as usual, so IE 7 doesn't support this header, but I don't think anybody is targeting IE 7 anymore.

See [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Browser_Support) for details on support in browser versions.

So in short no, you don't need framebusting code in addition to X-Frame-Options.